# sql pivot table (date, string)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table

[image]

```
Select * from Table1.
```

How can I write select to look like table 2?

[image]

Date range is selected by user and Hours column is a string type.

Example:
User wants a report of hours for every worker between 1.1.2015 and 1.3.2015.
So he enter FROM 1.1.2015 (dateTime picker) and TO 1.3.2015 (dateTime picker).

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry, It's for MS SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PIVOT syntax by using MIN or MAX as agregation for the HOURS column given that in this case it retrives a single value per WORKER/DATE. Hope it works for you.

```
declare @str varchar(MAX)
declare @q varchar(MAX)
declare @fromDate date
declare @toDate date

set @fromDate ='2015-01-01'
set @toDate ='2015-03-01'
set @str=''
select @str = @str + '[' + cast(DATE as varchar) + '],'
from (select distinct DATE from Table1 where DATE between @fromDate and @toDate) as A

set @q =
'SELECT WORKER, '+left(@str,len(@str)-1)+'
FROM 
(SELECT WORKER, DATE, HOURS
FROM Table1) p
PIVOT
(
MIN (HOURS)
FOR [DATE] IN
( '+left(@str,len(@str)-1)+' )
) AS pvt'
exec (@q)
```

Comment: I cannot use MIN function if HOURS column is string. And I also need for any date interval not just specific 2 days.

Comment: You can user MIN/MAX for a string column in SQL. For the distinct dates the only idea I have is to use a dynamic query. i just edited my answer. Hope it works

Comment: It works, thank you, but I don't know how to change it to accept input values, so user can enter date interval from - to.

Comment: FROM and TO doesn't come from the same data?. Probably you need to rephrase your question to include ALL you need

Comment: I did add an example.

Comment: You want the full range of days between FROM and TO, or only the days that have data?

Comment: I want only the days that have data.